# As3 & PHP URLEncoding problem!

Tags: php, mysql, flash, actionscript-3

I'm stuck with a stupid problem of encoding.

My problem is that all my accentuated characters are displayed as weird iso characters.

Example : é is displayed %E9

I send a string to my php file :

```
XMLLoader.load(new URLRequest(online+"/query.php?Query=" + q));
XMLLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,XMLLoaded);
```

When I trace q, I get :

> "INSERT INTO hello_world (message)
>   values('éàaà');"

**The GOOD query**

My php file look like this :

```
<?php 

include("conection.php");//Conectiong to database

$Q = $_GET['Query'];

$query = $Q;
$resultID = mysql_query($query) or die("Could not execute or probably SQL statement malformed (error): ". mysql_error());

$xml_output = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n"; // XML header
$xml_output .= "<answers>\n";

$xml_output .= "<lastID id=".'"'.mysql_insert_id().'"'." />\n";

$xml_output .= "<query string=".'"'.$query.'"'." />\n";

$xml_output .= "</answers>";

echo $xml_output;//Output the XML

?>
```

When I get back my XML into flash the $query looks like this :

> "INSERT INTO hello_world (message)
>   values('%E9%E0a%E0');"

And these values are then displayed into my DB which is annoying.

Any help would be appreciated! Cheers.

Jk_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is now solved!

As **andr** wrote down above, it's really a bad idea to use GET to send a queries.

It seems that when I sent the data from Flash using :

```
XMLLoader.load(new URLRequest(online+"/query.php?Query=" + q));
```

the URL was encoded and even with urldecode I got a blank entry in my DB.

So thanks to **andr** and **raz-l** I changed the way I send the data to my php file.

In flash I use URLVariables and in PHP I build my query:

```
variables = new URLVariables();
variables.Query = "éàûï ceci est un test...";
request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;         
request.data = variables;
XMLLoader.load(request);
```

And my php file looks like this :

```
$Q = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Query']);
$query = "INSERT INTO hello_world (message) values ('".$Q."')";
```

Jk_

Comment: `$Q = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Query']);`. "solved"!.

Comment: Yeah better like this! Thank you Colonel.

Answer (score 1):

[urldecode](http://lv.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) will do the job.

On the side note, it is **very** bad practice to send queries like that. Send the necessary data, filter it and then construct the query, unless you're building a clone of phpMyAdmin.

Comment: In my case it's easier because I address different queries to the same php file from one as3 class.

Comment: But I can understand why it is very bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

flash may be requesting the url with encoded parameter/querystring so decode it in php using urlencode.

i.e

$Q = urldecode($_GET['Query']);

Comment: The problem when I do it this way, is that my DATA base field message is empty! Data has been sent to the DB but the field is empty...

Comment: it may be problem with ur database... is it accepting utf8chars? is the message length within its range?

Answer (score 0):

$q = mysql_real_escape_string(urldecode($_GET['Query']));